# Create PayPal Transaction with checkout-server-sdk and react-paypal-js

Tags: reactjs, paypal

I'm currently using @paypal/react-paypal-js components within my React SPA.

```
        <PayPalScriptProvider options={options}>
            <PayPalButtons 
                fundingSource={FUNDING.PAYPAL} 
                style={{ color: "blue", shape: "pill", label: "pay", height: 40 }}
                createOrder={this.createOrder}
                onApprove={this.onApprove}
                onCancel={this.onCancel}
                onError={this.onError}
            />
        </PayPalScriptProvider>
```

Creating an order for me on server side works, but then when I pass the orderID back to the client side, it fails to work with the paypal button. This is my createOrder function.

```
createOrder(data, actions) {

    var cart = cookie.load('cart');

    axios.post('/todos/createPayPalOrder', {items: {cart: cart}})
        .then((res) => {
            console.log(res);

            this.setState({
                datum: data,
                order: res.data
            })

            return res.data;
        })

    /*
    var order = actions.order.create({
        purchase_units: [{
            
            amount: {
                value: this.state.price,
                currency_code: 'USD'
            },  
        }],
    });

    this.setState({
        datum: data,
        order: order
    })
    */

    //console.log(order);
    
    //return order;
    
}
```

This is my createOrder on the server side:

```
createOrder: async function(req, res) {

    const { items } = req.body;

    var amount = await calculateOrderAmount(req.body.items)

    let request = new paypal.orders.OrdersCreateRequest();
    request.prefer("return=representation");
    request.requestBody({
        intent: "CAPTURE",
        purchase_units: [
            {
                amount: {
                    currency_code: "USD",
                    value: "100.00"
                }
            }
        ]
    });


    let response = await client.execute(request);
    console.log(`Response: ${JSON.stringify(response)}`)

    console.log(`Order: ${JSON.stringify(response.result)}`);
    
    res.status(200).json(response.result.id);
},
```

When I try to return the orderID to the client side through createPayPalOrder, it always fails. It claims there is no orderid even though the orderid gets sent back to the client.

https://gyazo.com/5542a97135a60fae3eb8c2e912439e7e

https://gyazo.com/7445432a076767a7bbff550e74ed09bb

Is there an asynchronous error here or something? How do I get the PayPal button component to recognize the orderID that I sent back from the server side?

Answer (score 1):

Your createOrder function is not returning anything to its caller, which expects an id string or promise to be returned.

Return the `axios.post` promise...

```
return axios.post('/todos/createPayPalOrder', {items: {cart: cart}})
```